# Iterating through multiple pandas dataframes and sqlite select/insert queries

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, for-loop, if-statement

I know I've made ugly beginner mistakes so I'm not looking for anyone to invest time in coding a solution but instead to point me in a direction where I can figure this out and fix it for myself.

I've written a Python script that pulls data from SQLITE3 into a Pandas DataFrame (df_1).  I pull some data from that DataFrame to make up the SQL query used to pull data from a different table in the same database and create a second dataframe (df_2).  Then I iterate through df_2 to perform calculations on the data and eventually append that row back to a third table in the same database. The SQL queries all work as expected and provide the data that I'm looking for.

```
df_1 = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT... from 1st table)
    for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
    # Get initial data set and variables for 2nd query...
        if row >= 51:
            # Get data set for calculations on data 50 records before and up to event
            df_2 = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT... from 2nd table)
            # Perform calculations on the data and store those for future use
            df_3.to_sql('INSERT INTO...3rd table)
```

I'm only dealing with +/- 3000 rows but I expect it to grow over time. Iterating and writing to the 3rd table takes 30 seconds to a minute right now but I know that can be vastly improved and will only get worse if I don't fix the issues I've created.

I've tried writing to a CSV file for each row, appending all rows to a single CSV, and appending to a 4th dataframe and then pushing that to the database but none of those makes the calculation and 3rd table population significantly faster or more efficient. At this point I don't believe the problem is so much in the database update, it's in the way I'm approaching the initial select and iteration process.

Comment: I would pull it all out into separate functions. df_1_get_data_for_df2(), df_2_get_data_for_df_3(), df_3_insert_db(). Iterating a dataframe is never a good way to use pandas.